# nested_form fieldRemoved event not triggering recalculation properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using nested_form to create an invoice form with multiple invoice_line_items. I am then using javascript to calculate totals while the user enters their info. Everything works fine except the fieldRemoved listener event isn't triggering a recalculation. Here's my js:

```
function calculate_invoice() {
  $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);

  function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    // for each row:
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
      // get the values from this row:
      var $quantity = $('.quantity', this).val();
      var $rate = $('.rate', this).val();
      var $total = ($quantity * 1) * ($rate * 1);
      // set total for the row
      $('.multTotal', this).text($total);
        mult += $total;
      });
    $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  calculate_invoice();
});

$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
  calculate_invoice();
});

// not working
$(document).on('nested:fieldRemoved', function(event){
  calculate_invoice();
});
```

I placed a console output to make sure the js function is triggering properly and it is. However, the page doesn't recalculate. Here's my page's view:

```
 %table.table#line_items_table
        %thead
          %td &nbsp;
          %td Description
          %td Quantity
          %td Rate
          %td Total
        %tbody#line-items
          = f.fields_for :invoice_line_items, :wrapper => false do |line_item|
            %tr.txtMult.fields
              %td= line_item.link_to_remove "X"
              %td= line_item.text_field :description, :label => false
              %td= line_item.text_field :quantity, :class => "input-mini quantity", :label => false, :id => "quantity"
              %td= line_item.text_field :rate, :class => "input-mini rate", :label => false, :id => "rate"
              %td.multTotal 0
      %p#grandTotal.pull-right 0
      %p= f.link_to_add "Add", :invoice_line_items, :data => { :target => "#line-items" }, :id => "hello"
      .form-actions
        = f.submit "Preview Invoice", :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right"
```

Why isn't this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that when you remove fields with the `nested_form` gem, the fields themselves are not removed, only hidden. Specifically, it adds `style="display: none;"` to the `.fields` element, so you'll want to exclude those elements when you loop through to calculate your subtotal. Changing the loop in your `multInputs()` to exclude the hidden elements should fix the problem, for example using:

```
$("tr.txtMult:visible").each(function () { ... })
// or
$("tr.txtMult").not("[style]").each(function () { ... })
```

Comment: No need to substitute anything in, just put it exactly as above. `[style]` is a css selector that will match any element with the `style` attribute set, which will match the elements that `nested_form` has hidden.

Comment: $("tr.txtMult:visible").each(function () {  worked too...any downside of using :visible?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, just didn't occur to me 'cause it's not something I've used personally. Basically anything that will eliminate the hidden fields will work. Might update my answer to include it :)